# Steps in max(R)

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R:=\mathbb{R}^{[0,1]}$ and let $m:=\{f\in R:f(0)=0\}$. Prove, that $m\in Max(R)$.

I don't understand this exercise. How steps I must do?

Comment: What is $\mathrm{Max}(R)$?

Comment: @ClementC. presumably, the set of maximal ideals of the ring $R$

Comment: This is the ideal of maximum.

Comment: (thanks -- I didn't now that notation)

Comment: Similar to http://math.stackexchange.com/q/504140/589.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Consider the map $E: R \to \mathbb R$ given by $E(f)=f(0)$.
Prove that $E$  is a surjective ring homomorphism. Compute its kernel.

Comment: This also works when $R$ is the ring of *continuous* functions on $[0,1]$.